# Pyspark: Order by values of one column, but generate group id based on another column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, group

I have a dataframe like this

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

have = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('a', 'r1', '1'),
    ('b', 'r1', '2'),
    ('c', 'r1', '3'),
    ('d', 's3', '4'),
    ('e', 's3', '5'),
    ('f', 's4', '6'),
    ('g', 'r1', '7')],
    ['id', 'group_col', 'order_col'])
```

I want to create a group ID column based on the `group_col`, but only when the group changes. So when the r1 group comes up again, it gets a different group ID than the first r1's that appear.

```
want = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('a', 'r1', '1', '1'),
    ('b', 'r1', '2', '1'),
    ('c', 'r1', '3', '1'),
    ('d', 's3', '4', '2'),
    ('e', 's3', '5', '2'),
    ('f', 's4', '6', '3'),
    ('g', 'r1', '7', '4')],
    ['id', 'group_col', 'order_col', 'rleid'])

want.show()
+---+---------+---------+-----+
| id|group_col|order_col|rleid|
+---+---------+---------+-----+
|  a|       r1|        1|    1|
|  b|       r1|        2|    1|
|  c|       r1|        3|    1|
|  d|       s3|        4|    2|
|  e|       s3|        5|    2|
|  f|       s4|        6|    3|
|  g|       r1|        7|    4|
+---+---------+---------+-----+
```

The group IDs don't have to be contiguous, I just need a way for each group to be unique.

Basically I want something like the [rleid function](https://rdrr.io/cran/data.table/man/rleid.html) in the data.table R package. The equivalent R code would be:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(
    id = letters[1:7],
    group_col = c("r1", "r1", "r1", "s3", "s3", "s4", "r1"),
    order_col = c(1:7)
)
setorder(df, order_col)
df[, `:=` (rleid = rleid(group_col))]
df
   id group_col order_col rleid
1:  a        r1         1     1
2:  b        r1         2     1
3:  c        r1         3     1
4:  d        s3         4     2
5:  e        s3         5     2
6:  f        s4         6     3
7:  g        r1         7     4
```

I have tried `rank()` and `dense_rank()` over `group_col`.
E.g.

```
df = have.withColumn("rleid", F.dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy('group_col')))
df.show()
+---+---------+---------+-----+
| id|group_col|order_col|rleid|
+---+---------+---------+-----+
|  a|       r1|        1|    1|
|  b|       r1|        2|    1|
|  c|       r1|        3|    1|
|  g|       r1|        7|    1|
|  d|       s3|        4|    2|
|  e|       s3|        5|    2|
|  f|       s4|        6|    3|
+---+---------+---------+-----+
```

This doesn't give me what I want because id=g should have rleid=4.

I have also tried `array_sort()` based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68380054/rank-values-in-spark-on-a-column-based-on-previous-values), but unfortunately this didn't work either.

```
df = (have
    .withColumn("rank", F.array_sort(F.collect_set('group_col').over(Window.orderBy('order_col').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow))))
    .withColumn('rleid', F.expr("array_position(rank, group_col)")))

df.show()
+---+---------+---------+------------+-----+
| id|group_col|order_col|        rank|rleid|
+---+---------+---------+------------+-----+
|  a|       r1|        1|        [r1]|    1|
|  b|       r1|        2|        [r1]|    1|
|  c|       r1|        3|        [r1]|    1|
|  d|       s3|        4|    [r1, s3]|    2|
|  e|       s3|        5|    [r1, s3]|    2|
|  f|       s4|        6|[r1, s3, s4]|    3|
|  g|       r1|        7|[r1, s3, s4]|    1|
+---+---------+---------+------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the current and previous rows in group_col to flag the boundary points where group changes, then calculate the cumulative sum over the boundary condition to assign unique id

```
W = Window.orderBy('order_col')
cond = F.lag('group_col').over(W) != F.col('group_col')
want = have.withColumn('rleid', F.coalesce(F.sum(cond.cast('int')).over(W), F.lit(0)))
```

---

```
want.show()

+---+---------+---------+-----+
| id|group_col|order_col|rleid|
+---+---------+---------+-----+
|  a|       r1|        1|    0|
|  b|       r1|        2|    0|
|  c|       r1|        3|    0|
|  d|       s3|        4|    1|
|  e|       s3|        5|    1|
|  f|       s4|        6|    2|
|  g|       r1|        7|    3|
+---+---------+---------+-----+
```